# Fabrication gem won't let me run `rails console` with the error: 'model_name' is already defined when implementing for rspec factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory, fabrication-gem

The [Fabrication gem](https://www.fabricationgem.org/) is making me unable to run rails console because it complains that the Factory models I'm creating with it are already defined in my app/models.

For instance, I have an `Issue` model in my `app/models` that looks like:

```
class Issue
  include Virtus.model

  attribute  :id,      String, :default => ""
  attribute  :summary, String, :default => ""

end
```

I'm creating a sample of this model while testing in `spec/factories/issue.rb` that looks like:

```
Fabricator(:issue) do
  id      "00001"
  summary "test summary"
end
```

Anyway, I think that rails console freaks out because then there are two definitions of Issue. However, both my rspec tests and application run fine.

The error I'm getting specifically is:

```
/Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/fabrication-2.16.3/lib/fabrication/schematic/manager.rb:62:in `raise_if_registered': 'issue' is already defined (Fabrication::DuplicateFabricatorError)
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/fabrication-2.16.3/lib/fabrication/schematic/manager.rb:28:in `register'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/fabrication-2.16.3/lib/fabrication.rb:60:in `Fabricator'
    from /Users/beckah/Perforce/beckah_Beckahs-MacBook-Pro_CO-1:_MVP_Tree_View/nemedio_qms/spec/factories/issues.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/reload.rb:6:in `reload'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:263:in `block in invoke_after_fork_callbacks'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:262:in `each'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:262:in `invoke_after_fork_callbacks'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:198:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/beckah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How can I load `rails console` while still implementing Fabrication for my rspec tests?

Answer (score 0):

Fabrication automatically loads the defined fabricators when you try to fabricate something. It also checks to make sure you don't accidentally define the same fabricator twice as that can cause confusing issues in your codebase. It's likely that you're seeing this because something in your application is loading fabricators twice.

Worth noting that if you don't actually try to fabricate something fabrication will not attempt to load the fabricators at all. If you're seeing this immediately when you run console it's likely you have 2 instances in your codebase where fabricators are being loaded outside of its own process.

I also replied on the issue against fabrication itself: https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/issues/302#issuecomment-330935726